# Expressing percentage

Tags: subquery, ms-access-2007, percentage

I need to be able to divide the values of each record in a certain field contained in a query result by the sum of all the values in the same field. This will enable me to calculate the percentage that each record is of the whole. The results must be expressed in the same domain in a new field.

That is: Each record in ColumnA must be divided by the sum of ColumnA, then expressed as a fraction/percentage in a new, neigbouring ColumnB.

I have tried this in Query1:

Total: (select sum(ColumnA) from Query1) - then in a second subquery Percentage:([CountOfColumnA/Total])

This worked once, but Access stopped me with a circular error because of the Query1 from Query1.

Now I am trying to rewrite it and reach the answer in only one subquery to avoid the circular problem. I can easily do this in Excel, but don't know enough about expressions and coding to manage it in Access.

I found a question on this forum from someone with a similar question, but I do not understand the answer  - I do not know enough about SQL (nothing actually) to adapt it to my problem. My adaptation was something like this:

SELECT Query1, ColumnA / ((SELECT SUM(ColumnA) FROM Records) AS Percentage FROM Records

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *Query1* is a strange field name, try with:

```
Select
    Query1, 
    ColumnA,
        ColumnA / (Select Sum(T.ColumnA) From Records As T) As
    Percentage 
From 
    Records
```